# file path instead of typing actual password

Tags: command-line, password, authentication

I'm still a novice with Ubuntu, Git and GitHub and recently GitHub removed remote authentication using password from terminal, instead it now requires personal access token to authenticate and push.

Is it possible to store personal access token into a plain text file and print the content of file using command ?
or assigning a key combination for the same ?

and if not, what other efficient methods you use to input such password or token which essentially is long string of random character, impossible to remember ?

Currently, I simply open the file and copy paste the token, but it's a bit cumbersome task as i keep cutting and pasting codes from one file to another.

Comment: More generally, you can use `keepassxc` for password management.  That has a facility to "click a button" to paste a password in (provided you have unlocked it).  I don't know of a way to copy and paste a 2FA token, though.

Comment: @Ray `keepassxc` can also manage TOTP 2FA and has the ability to copy/paste

Comment: Github allows ssh-key based authentication. You should use that instead of passwords.